# STM8L ADC multiple channel read problem

Tags: adc, three-phase, stm8

I am using an STM8L151Cx with the Cosmic C compiler to develop a 3 phase ammeter. I rsn into an issue during my last stage of development.

3 phase current is connected to 3 channels in the controller via op-amps. I calibrated the ADC channels so that it shows the current injected into it over the display connected to the controller.

When I operate it only by injecting current to a single ADC keeping other ADC channels open, the display shows correct a reading (i.e. exact injected current is been shown in the display.) The ADC calibration is correct and the meter is working perfectly.

Next I started injecting 3 phases simultaneously, and the problem started.

When all the 3 phases are injected simultaneously, the reading dropped from the actual current injected. It is not showing the actual injected current reading. I cross checked whether the ADC reading measured is correct. There is a drop in the ADC reading value for about 8-12 points, so there is a problem in the ADC reading.

I measured the voltage levels a ADC channel port using a multimeter. There is no change in voltage level when I inject a single phase or three phase current, so there is some problem with my ADC code. I think the problem is with my ADC READ. I am sharing my adc_read code here.

```
uint16_t ADC_Read(ADC_Channel_TypeDef ADC_Channel_No)
{
  uint16_t ADCval = 0;

  ADC_DeInit(ADC1);

  ADC_Init(ADC1, ADC_ConversionMode_Single, ADC_Resolution_12Bit, ADC_Prescaler_1);
  ADC_VrefintCmd(DISABLE);
  ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
  ADC_ChannelCmd(ADC1, ADC_Channel_No, ENABLE);
  ADC_SoftwareStartConv(ADC1);
  while(ADC_GetFlagStatus(ADC1, ADC_FLAG_EOC) == FALSE);
    ADCval = ADC_GetConversionValue(ADC1);
    ADC_ClearFlag(ADC1, ADC_FLAG_EOC);
  ADC_DeInit(ADC1);
  return ADCval;
}
```

Can someone help me in identifying the problem? I think the problem is with reading multiple ADC channels. Here I read multiple channels one by one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop(ignore the result) 2 or 3 reads after change ADC channel.